# Can not run Matlab multiple version due to License Manager Error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to install matlab,and everything went fine ,and was installed until i tried running it.I keep getting the following error:

```
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -114
This release of MATLAB requires a License Manager update and a new License File from the License

License Path:[...]C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Mathworks\MATLAB\R2014_a_licenses\license.dat;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\licenses\[name if pc]a.lic
Licensing error:-114,582.
```

Does anyone know why do i getthis error and what can i do to fix it ?

Comment: You should contact MathWorks with your licensing issues. They're the ones that sold you the license, so they're the ones that should make sure it works for you.

Comment: alternatively, your local it support (company or university) may be able to help.

Comment: did you _activate_ matlab after the installation?

Comment: Yes i did activate it .